# java association of a class to itself

Tags: java, associations

I am new to Java and am struggling with associations. I have a class

```
public class A{
  private string name;

  public string get_name() {
    return name;
  }

  public void set_name(string name) {
    name = name;
  }
}
```

I have an association with another class B as `association A -> B`. It is one to one association. Now what I would like to do is to create another class `C` which is of type `class A`. So in other words, C is the same class as A but with different name. But there is 1 to many association between A and C. I would appreciate any help!

Comment: If `C` **is** `A` with a different name why not just initialize an instance of `A` and name it `C`?

Comment: wha? Your question doesn't make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `C` **is** `A` with a different name why not just initialize an instance of `A` and name it `C`?

```
A c = new A();
c.set_name("Bob");
```

Alternatively, if `C`is going to change over time but be reliant on `A` make `C` extend `A`

```
public class C extends A{

}
```

However, I would be wary of using the above as its generally a bad idea to make a superclass concrete (What if A changes down the line and you don't want C to inherit those changes?). So, make `A` an interface/abstract class and make both `C` and `Aconcrete` implement it.

Something like the following would be good...

```
abstract class A{
  protected String name; //Protected so that subclasses can call it

  public String get_name() {
     return name;
  }

  public void set_name(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

}

class C extends A{


}

class Aconcrete extends A{

}
```

Comment: +1 for the tip of avoiding concrete superclasses. Maybe people don't intuit that well (yet).

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question right, this is what you want:

```
public class A{
  private Collection<A> myCs;
  private string name;

  public string get_name() {
    return name;
  }

  public void set_name(string name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

Having the Collection `myCs` in the class `A` is your one-to-many association. You don't need an extra class `C` if it would have the same parameters as `A`.

*By the way: the setter in your code has a bug. I've fixed it above.*

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a second class - you might need a second (and 100 more) object(s). A typical case is a recursive Datastructure like a tree, which consists of nodes:

```
public class Node {
  private List<Node> childs = new ArrayList <Node> ();

  public boolean isLeaf () {
    return childs.isEmpty ();
  }

  public void add (Child c) {
    childs.add (c);
  }
}
```

(simplified)

The compiler has no problem in constructing such a class, which uses a definition which isn't ready at that time.

Maybe the developer of the compiler had. :)